# Getting DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError] ,incorrect integer value

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, node-modules

I am trying to develop a mini shopping site, wherein I am doing this using NodeJs Express and MySQL

my cart could have many products and each product could belong to multiple carts.

Therefore using sequelize,my relations are as follows:

```
Cart.belongsToMany(Product, { through: CartItem });
Product.belongsToMany(Cart, { through: CartItem });
```

Now CartItem is another table that maps between cartid and productid.

Each of these table have been designed as follows.

**Product**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

    const sequelize = require('../util/database');

    const Product = sequelize.define('product', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      title: Sequelize.STRING,
      price: {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
        allowNull: false
      },
      imageUrl: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }
    });

    module.exports = Product;
```

**Cart**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = require('../util/database');

const Cart = sequelize.define('cart', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  }
});

module.exports = Cart;
```

**CartItem**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = require('../util/database');

const CartItem = sequelize.define('cartItem', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  quantity: Sequelize.INTEGER
});

module.exports = CartItem;
```

I am trying to add a product to my cart. The logic is to retrieve the list of all available items in the cart. If the product that I am adding already exists, then I just increase the quantity.Else I add it afresh.

The code to do that is as follows:

```
module.exports.postCart = (req, res, next) => {
    const prodId = req.body.productId;
    let fetchedCart;
    let qty=1;
    req.user.getCart()
        .then(cart => {
            fetchedCart = cart;
            console.log('cart', cart);
            return cart.getProducts({where:{id:prodId}});
        })
        .then(products => {
            let productInCart;
            if (products.length > 0) {
                productInCart = products[0];
            }
            if (productInCart) {
                const oldQuantity = productInCart.cartItem.quantity;
                qty = oldQuantity + 1;
                return productInCart;
              }
              //console.log(Product.findByPk(prodId));
              return Product.findByPk(prodId);
        })
        .then(product => {
            console.log('product',product);

            return fetchedCart.addProduct(product, {
                through: { quantity: qty }
              });
        })
        .then(() => {
            res.redirect('/cart');
          })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
};
```

Problem is that whenever I try to add a particular product to cart ,I end up with this error. I can see solutions to a lot of similar usecases here,but not related to the problem that I am facing at the moment.

Error Stack Trace.

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `quantity`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `cartId`, `productId` FROM 

`cartItems` AS `cartItem` WHERE `cartItem`.`cartId` = 1 AND `cartItem`.`productId` IN ('[object SequelizeInstance:product]');

Executing (default): INSERT INTO `cartItems` (`id`,`quantity`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`cartId`,`productId`) VALUES (NULL,1,'2020-02-22 07:39:45','2020-02-22 07:39:45',1,'[object SequelizeInstance:product]');
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: Incorrect integer value: '[object SequelizeInstance:product]' 


for column 'productId' at row 1    at Query.formatError (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:244:16)
    at Query.handler [as onResult] (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:51:23)
    at Query.execute (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:30:14)
    at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:417:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:75:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:82:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',

  parent: Error: Incorrect integer value: '[object SequelizeInstance:product]' for column 'productId' at row 1
      at Packet.asError (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:712:17)
      at Query.execute (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:417:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:75:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:82:25)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
    code: 'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD',
    errno: 1366,
    sqlState: 'HY000',
    sqlMessage: "Incorrect integer value: '[object SequelizeInstance:product]' for column 'productId' at row 1",



      sql: "INSERT INTO `cartItems` (`id`,`quantity`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`cartId`,`productId`) VALUES (NULL,1,'2020-02-22 07:39:45','2020-02-22 07:39:45',1,'[object SequelizeInstance:product]');",
        parameters: undefined

  },

  original: Error: Incorrect integer value: '[object SequelizeInstance:product]' for column 'productId' at row 1
      at Packet.asError (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:712:17)
      at Query.execute (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:417:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:75:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aravind\Documents\workspace-VSC\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:82:25)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
    code: 'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD',
    errno: 1366,
    sqlState: 'HY000',
    sqlMessage: "Incorrect integer value: '[object SequelizeInstance:product]' for column 'productId' at row 1",
    sql: "INSERT INTO `cartItems` (`id`,`quantity`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`cartId`,`productId`) VALUES (NULL,1,'2020-02-22 07:39:45','2020-02-22 07:39:45',1,'[object SequelizeInstance:product]');",
    parameters: undefined
  },
  sql: "INSERT INTO `cartItems` (`id`,`quantity`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`cartId`,`productId`) VALUES (NULL,1,'2020-02-22 07:39:45','2020-02-22 07:39:45',1,'[object SequelizeInstance:product]');",
  parameters: undefined
}
```

**Can someone please tell me what wrong I am doing here. I am able to console.log() the value of product as follows, which I think is correct.**

```
product product {
  dataValues: {
    id: 1,
    title: "Children's book",
    price: 20,
    imageUrl: 'orth-dakota-sunflower.jpg',
    description: 'https://dynai5135742-02-n',
    createdAt: 2020-02-22T10:05:22.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-02-22T10:05:22.000Z
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    id: 1,
    title: "Children's book",
    price: 20,
    imageUrl: 'orth-dakota-sunflower.jpg',
    description: 'https://dynai5135742-02-n',
    createdAt: 2020-02-22T10:05:22.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-02-22T10:05:22.000Z
  },
  _changed: {},
  _modelOptions: {
    timestamps: true,
    validate: {},
    freezeTableName: false,
    underscored: false,
    paranoid: false,
    rejectOnEmpty: false,
    whereCollection: { id: '1' },
    schema: null,
    schemaDelimiter: '',
    defaultScope: {},
    scopes: {},
    indexes: [],
    name: { plural: 'products', singular: 'product' },
    omitNull: false,
    sequelize: Sequelize {
      options: [Object],
      config: [Object],
      dialect: [MysqlDialect],
      queryInterface: [QueryInterface],
      models: [Object],
      modelManager: [ModelManager],
      connectionManager: [ConnectionManager],
      importCache: {}
    },
    hooks: {}
  },
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    raw: true,
    attributes: [
      'id',
      'title',
      'price',
      'imageUrl',
      'description',
      'createdAt',
      'updatedAt'
    ]
  },
  isNewRecord: false
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, after returning the product you found with `return Product.findByPk(prodId);`, your next `then`, is receiving it as `product.product`. So it should be:

```
.then(product => {
  console.log('product', product.product);

  return fetchedCart.addProduct(product.product, {
    through: { quantity: qty }
  });
})
```

EDIT 1:

My bad, got it wrong. I believe then, you'll need to get the plain data instead:

```
.then(product => {
  const plainProduct = product.get({ plain: true }); 

  return fetchedCart.addProduct(plainProduct, {
    through: { quantity: qty }
  });
})
```

Comment: No .."product product" is the result of console.log(product,product). Moreover  console.log('product', product.product); is returning 'product undefined'

Comment: {
  id: 1,
  title: 'Jataka Tales',
  price: 45,
  imageUrl: 'efg',
  description: 'plainProduct',
  createdAt: 2020-02-22T13:34:59.000Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-02-22T13:34:59.000Z
}
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `cartItems` (`id`,`quantity`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`cartId`,`productId`) VALUES (NULL,1,'2020-02-22 13:35:01','2020-02-22 13:35:01',1,'[object Object]');
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: Incorrect integer value: '[object Object]' for column 'productId' at row 1                                                                     Here is what I am getting now

Comment: @aravindnarayanan Alright, I'm gonna need to see that `addProduct` method.

Comment: As far as I know,addProduct is a method that is auto provided by Sequelize ORM to insert a record into the table Product...it doesn't have an explicit body. It takes in a product object and inserts it into the table .

Comment: Okay, I know about this feature. I was hoping you'd say otherwise.

Comment: Are you able to think of anything else that I could be doing wrongly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208329/discussion-between-aravind-narayanan-and-nick-rameau).

Comment: The last thing I could think of is that, no offense, but you're doing your relationships wrong. You could keep them simpler by adding the product_id and the cart_id in the cartItem table.